# How to add variables to prefix path?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.3

Below is the code:

```
- name: List keys simple
  s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    mode: list
    prefix: "/{{a}}/{{b}}/tmp/"
  register: foo

- name: when you need the result
  debug:
    msg: 'print this'
  when: "{{foo.s3_keys |length}} > 0"
```

---

where variables `a` & `b` are used

Can we avoid double quotes(`" "`) for `prefix:` & `when:`?

Comment: Why do you care about double quotes?

Comment: @larsks Because I don't want to use double quotes, when I don't need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consistently use double quotes for your strings you will avoid a number of common errors.  For example, this:

```
somestring: yes
```

Will not actually set `somestring` to the string value `yes` (you actually get the boolean value `true`).  And this:

```
somestring: 12:34
```

Will not set `somestring` to the string value `12:34` (you actually get `754`). In other words, you need double quotes in a number of situations you might not expect, so you're better off using them whenver you have a string value.

---

With respect to your specific question:

The value for `prefix:` does not require double quotes. This is fine:

```
- name: List keys simple
  s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    mode: list
    prefix: /{{a}}/{{b}}/tmp/
  register: foo
```

This works because the value does not start with a character that has any special meeting to YAML.

On the other hand, you need to use double quotes in your `when:` statement, because the value starts with a `{`, which in YAML indicates the start of a dictionary.

Comment: what about spaces between curly braces? `{{ a }}` or `{{a}}`

Comment: Those two expressions are identical.